# Leverage browser caching and Specify a cache validator? 

Tags: cache, page-speed

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/enji.se/RVzr15zT

That's what my result looks like!

Does anyone know how to fix Leverage browser caching and Specify a cache validator?

I've googled it but didn't find anything. I have Apache.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Google Page Speed Documentation](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching):

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static
>   resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded
>   resources from local disk rather than over the network.

The [Apache Caching Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) should explain how to configure Apache accordingly.